# Adding parameters to webclient

Tags: java, spring-boot, webclient

I need help!

here is my webclient

```
private WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://address:port");

public Mono<RespDto> translate(AuthPrincipal principal, ReqDto dto, String token) {
    return client.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                    .path("/api")
                    .queryParam("id", dto.getId())
                    .queryParam("content", dto.getContent())
                    .queryParam("profile", dto.getProfile())
                    .build())
            .headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(token.split(" ")[1]))
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(RespDto.class);

}
```

and here is the controller for the api I'm trying to retrieve

```
@GetMapping("")
public Mono<?> trans(@AuthenticationPrincipal @ApiIgnore AuthPrincipal principal,
                     @Valid ReqDto reqDto) {
    return service.function(principal, reqDto);
}
```

So my problem is that the service function checks principal id for authority but I know how how to pass AuthPrincipal object via webclient...

please help the noob!

Comment: You don't. You pass your credentials/token or whatever is needed to authenticate you with the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already providing the Bearer authenticaton token with the following line of code: `.headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(token.split(" ")[1]))`. If this is working properly and you are able to authenticate yourself against the target API, then Spring will inject `AuthPrincipal` in the endpoint method (assuming your Spring Security configuration / customization is working correctly).